# PHP's shell_exec not running screen -dmS screen_name

Tags: php, shell-exec

I'm struggeling with the shell_exec function in PHP At the moment.
I'm trying to start a process with screen through PHP's `shell_exec()`;

For whatever reason the process does start without screen in the command.
But does not start when ran with screen in the command. 
What causes this and how can it be solved?

Comment: What is the exact command that you are running?  How are you checking to see that the process is/isn't running?

Comment: Redirect stderr so you can see the error message: `shell_exec("screen ... 2>&1")`